# Android : SMS is being received multiple times

Tags: android, service, sms

I have service which sends SMS at specified time but i noticed that same message is being received multiple times. don't know why it happens.

After setting a time to send SMS `11:45 pm`, i got same message 4 times at `11:45 pm`, `05:58 am`,`09:58 am` and `01:01 pm`

Here is my code for send SMS:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(AlarmActivity.this,
                    SendSmsService.class);
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(AlarmActivity.this, 0,
                    myIntent, 0);

            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, TimePreference.getHour(sendTime));
            cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, TimePreference.getMinute(sendTime));
            cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
                    pendingIntent);
```

And here is **SendSmsService.java**

```
public class SendSmsService extends Service
{
    private static final String TAG = SendSmsService.class.getSimpleName();

    String CompleteAddr, eContact1, eContact2, eContact3;
    String smsString;
    boolean acknowledged;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.v(TAG, "onStartCommand");
        getSharedSettings();

        if (acknowledged == false) {
            if (eContact1 != "")
                sendSMS(eContact1, smsString + CompleteAddr);
            if (eContact2 != "")
                sendSMS(eContact2, smsString + CompleteAddr);
            if (eContact3 != "")
                sendSMS(eContact3, smsString + CompleteAddr);
        }
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.onUnbind(intent);
    }

    private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message) {
        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
    }   
}
```

Any suggestion and idea will be appreciated 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In service use "onCreate" action for your main code and NOT "onStartCommand()".

Comment: Thanks for quick response, are you sure this would solve my problem ?

Comment: As I can see from your code you don't need to run service all the time. So just start it (AlarmManeger) and stop it after it finished send SMS (onCreate will run only once).

If you using onStartCommand() you can resoult that service will be paused and bring up by system (when you dont want it).

Comment: message is sent only once when first time service is created but after that every time `onStartcommand` is being called, so message couldn't be sent :(

Comment: After sending your message you can call **stopService()** to stop it, so it will be started again with **onCreate()** when you will call it.

If you have a reason to run service all the time then use **Handlers** to communicate with it!

Comment: can i use `stopself()` after sending sms because i am using this service with pendingIntenet so do i need to cancel this pendingIntent or stopself() will work?

Answer (score 0):

It could be a problem originate elswhere in your phone, preventing a correct response to a sent SMS.

I had the same problem with my Sony Xperia Pro (MK16i), running on Android 4.0.4 (ICS).

Whenever I install an app that turns the screen off on a shake, twist or turn the problem occurs: multiple copies of an SMS.
When I disable it or better even, uninstall it, everything turns out normal.
Apparently the App prevents SMS-Receive-Reports to be sent back tot the SMS provider (phone-company) 's Servers.
Then these think the SMS was not received (phone off or something alike) ant try is after 10 minutes or so (depending on the provider) again.
This causes multiple receipts. Until the phone get the opportunity to send a SMS-Receive-Reports back. Then the whole circus stops. Until the next SMS.

Try to see if something uses the Device-control slots (see settings-security). Try to disable it or uninstall it.
Or get a newer phone or Android version.
Otherwise, I also don't know.

Cheers,
Imre